# Using different colors for dropdown options using Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using a **Select2** drop-down, and would like to set different colors on options. I successfully changed all options to one color, but I want to variate between several ones basing on the value. I have close to 1000 options (pages in books) and I need to mark some of them (based on some set of pages) as green. May you propose the way to achieve this?

HTML

```
<label for="add-coord-page">P:  </label>
<select class="select2" id="add-coord-page" name="pages" style="width:60px"></select>
```

CSS

```
#select2-add-coord-page-results { 
    color: red;
}
```

Example:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5LJx.png)

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted a minimally reproducible example for what you've developed so far

Comment: Thanks. I added some code, but the task is better examplifed by the attached picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change select box option background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color)

Comment: Read it before. Not exactly what I need. Looking for cleaner way.

Comment: This is what answers my answer completely. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360783/how-to-render-html-in-select2-options Most useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `nth-child` on the `option` tag

```html
<style>
    option:nth-child(odd) {
        color: red;
    }
    option:nth-child(even) {
        color: green;
    }
</style>
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Very close, thanks Dan! Unfortunately, it is not exactly - odd/even. I have close to 1000 options (pages in books) and I need to mark some of them (based on some set of pages) as green.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The main problem was that selection2 dropdown options are created dynamically and no event is generated on it. That is the trick.

1. I marked all the pages that were supposed to change color by adding space.
2. Then on relevant event:

   ```
    // Set colors of pages containing images
    $('#add-coord-page').on('select2:open', function (e) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.select2-results__option:contains(" ")').css('color', SUCCESS_COLOR);
        }, 100);

    });
   ```

The timer places function changing color on the events loop.
Thanks everyone who tried help me.