# Using html tags options of select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I want to use HTML tags in Select2 options, but when I write that in the normal select box, it doesn't appear in Select2.

```
<option value="scary">
  scary <span>31</span>
<option>
```

after using select2, the options will appear in the below format

```
 <option value="scary">
      scary 31
    <option>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render html in select2 options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360783/how-to-render-html-in-select2-options)

Comment: Thank you @AntonioPetricca,
But I get my data from Select box not JSON or something like that !