# Autocomplete search with link on Name

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, search, autocomplete

I want to click on name in search box and open profile of that person. How can I add link on this item.firstname.  My route for user profile is  '/users/{id}'..

this is my javascript code for autocomplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.livesearch').select2({
            placeholder: 'Search users',
            ajax: {
                url: '/master/autocomplete',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.firstname+' '+item.lastname,
                                id: item.id,

                            }
                        })
                    };
                },
                cache: true,
            }
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

There is answer... I hope so that it can be helpful to someone..

Comment: Next time try to add code in textual form instead of an image. [Read why](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it works but you can try adding a tag instead of text like

```
text: `<a href='/users/item.id'>${item.firstname} ${item.lastname}</a>`
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360783/how-to-render-html-in-select2-options

Comment: Thank you, but this is not working... I tried, and I tried similar things

Answer (score 0):

u can try executing a function on selecting the option

```
$('select').on('select2:select', function (evt) {
   // get select value
  //page redirection
});
```

Comment: how to add this in my javascript code, I am not so familiar with javascript