# vue v-select2-component change the field height

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ui-select2

How to add or override the height of this `v-select2-component` ?
The field is so small,

Code sample for reference: https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2

Have tried but doest work: [How do I change select2 box height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824676/how-do-i-change-select2-box-height?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top)

```
Install
// npm install
npm install v-select2-component --save
Use as component
import as global component.
// import Select2Component
import Select2 from 'v-select2-component';

Vue.component('Select2', Select2);
new Vue({
    // ...
})
import into a single component.
// import Select2Component
import Select2 from 'v-select2-component';

<template>
  <div>
    <Select2 v-model="myValue" :options="myOptions" :settings="{ settingOption: value, settingOption: value }" @change="myChangeEvent($event)" @select="mySelectEvent($event)" />
    <h4>Value: {{ myValue }}</h4>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    // declare Select2Component
    components: {Select2},
    data() {
        return {
            myValue: '',
            myOptions: ['op1', 'op2', 'op3'] // or [{id: key, text: value}, {id: key, text: value}]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        myChangeEvent(val){
            console.log(val);
        },
        mySelectEvent({id, text}){
            console.log({id, text})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```